# Error: While loop in bash shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, do-while

I am trying to run simple script named `test.sh` which `echo` the numbers in ascending manner. But somehow it shows error.

```
#!/bin/bash

clear
a= 0

while [ $a <= 5 ];
do
    echo $a
    a=$(( a+1 ))
done
```

Error:

```
./test.sh: line 4: 0: command not found
./test.sh: line 6: =: No such file or directory
```

Comment: @abhi1610, you are taking "a" as counter but incrementing "n" !!! huhhhh

Comment: @anubhava Thank you for your info about the link. By your answer you would just print the numbers not iterate them. I want to iterate over the while loop.

Comment: @monk Thank you for spotting the typo error.

Comment: Iterate: `for n in {1..5}; do echo "$n"; done`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Way better is already mentioned by Anubhava, however this is correct version of your answer.

```
#!/bin/bash

clear
a=0

while [[ "$a" -lt 5 ]];
do
    echo $a
    a=$(($a+1))
done
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. For the curiosity can you describe why we can't use `<=` instead `-lt`?

Comment: its for integer comparison

Comment: You can use `<=` if you use the arithmetic statement: `while (( a <= 5 )); do`. `bash` doesn't have data types (all values are strings), so you need special commands and operators to specify whether you want to do string operations or treat the strings as integers.

Answer (score 1):

The first problem with your code is `a= 0`, spaces aren't allowed (before or after `=`) in assignment.

secondly, this part `[ $a <= 5 ]`. You have to use `-lt` instead of `<=` here.

As you are already familiar with the `(( ))` construct, I will recommend you to use that instead, which will let you compare integers with `<=`, `>=` etc..

Your code with the above modification:

```
#!/bin/bash

clear
a=0

while (( $a <= 5 ));
do
    echo $a
    a=$(( a+1 ))
done
```

Comment: Thanks for the descriptive answer.